# How to put a colon to the left of a set of equations?

Tags: equations, align, braces

Currently I have the following code

```
 \begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
 \Omega : \dot x &= \omega(b) \\
 p &= \sigma(z)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
```

Which generates

[image]

But I would much prefer something like

[image]

Is this possible? If it is too tough, can someone show me how to replace with the colon : with a left brace? That will work equally well for the intended purpose. Danke!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a simple by aligned environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
 \Omega : \begin{aligned}
            \dot x & = \omega(b) \\
                 p & = \sigma(z)
          \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*} 
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, it will be enough to vote for answer and if it will serve for you accept it :-)

Comment: Actually I need your help again :(

Comment: just ask. othervise I will not know, what you need ...