# How to put a colon to the left of a specific set of equations in a set of equation

Tags: formatting, equations, align

Following: [How to put a colon to the left of a set of equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305884/how-to-put-a-colon-to-the-left-of-a-set-of-equations)

Currently I have the following code

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Omega : \dot x &= \omega(b) \\
p &= \sigma(z)\\
m &= \xi(k)\\
q &= \dot {\partial L}{\partial q}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Which generates

[image]

But the : should be placed to the left of the first two equation, because it is not associated with the second set of equation...so I need something like this

[image]

Is there a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `align` instead of `equation` and than repeat `aligned` ...

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}% <-- for showing only equations
        \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

        \begin{document}
     \begin{align*}
 \Omega :&\ \begin{aligned}
            \dot x & = \omega(b) \\
                 p & = \sigma(z)
            \end{aligned}     \\
         &\  \begin{aligned}
            \xi & = \omega(b) \\
            q   & = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}
            \end{aligned}
     \end{align*} 
         \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is probably to load the `empheq`  package, which defines the eponymous environment, and use the `left =` key. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` in this case, since it loads `mathtools`, which itself loads the former.

I added a second solution, if you want to put $\Omega:$ in front of only the first two equations, based on `blkarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq, blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left =Ω:\enspace]{align*}
 \dot x &= ω(b) \\
p &= σ(z)\\
m &= ξ(k)\\
q &= \dot{∂ L}{∂ q}
\end{empheq}
\vskip1cm
\[ \begin{blockarray}{r@{{}={}}l}
\begin{block}{\Left{$ Ω:\enspace $}{.}r@{{}={}}l}
 \dot x & ω(b) \\
p & σ(z)\\
\end{block}
m & ξ(k)\\
m &\dot{∂ L}{∂ q}
\end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice idea to use `empheq`, however I understood OP, that he like to have `\Omega` in front of the first two equation on at all (as it is possible with empheq), that was reason, that I didn't use it :-)

Comment: Actually I wondered whether the O.P. wanted to have Ω just in front of the first two equations or on front of all. I've added another solution for this case.

Comment: I saw your edit. This is new to me.  I'm sorry, but cannot vote twice for your answer :-( ... I need to read `empheq` documentation again :-)

Answer (score 2):

use `\left. \begin{aligned}.....\end{aligned}\right.`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\Omega :
\left.
\begin{aligned}
 \dot x &= \omega(b) \\
p &= \sigma(z)\\
m &= \xi(k)\\
q &= \dot {\partial L}{\partial q}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]